# How to implement non-recursive fill algorithm

Tags: c++, stack, queue

I am trying to implement a non-recursive fill algorithm with stack and queue. I have a pseudo code that I follow, that looks like this:

```
procedure fill(r,k)
clickedColor = imageElement( r,k )
insert (r,k) into todoList
while todoList is not empty
   get (r,k) from todoList
   if r,k is inside image and imageElement(r,k) equals clickedColor
   then imageElement(r,k) = newColor
   insert all four neighbors into todoList
```

I am unsure what to do with procedure fill(x,y).
 This is the code I got for the stack which do not work, it pops the same r coordinate but different for the k which is weird::

```
struct RK {
RK(int r, int k): _r(r),_k(k) {}
int _r;
int _k;
};

void nonRecursiveFillStack(int r, int k, IDrawingParent *pImage, QColor 
colorOld, QColor colorNew){

   deque <RK> stack;
   colorOld = pImage->pixel(r, k);
   stack.push_back(RK (r, k) );
   while(!stack.empty()){
       RK rk = stack.back();
       stack.pop_back();
       if(pImage->isInside(rk._r, rk._k) and pImage->pixel(rk._r, rk._k) == colorOld){
           qDebug() << "pop: (" << rk._r << ", " << rk._k << ")";
           pImage->pixel(rk._r, rk._k) = colorNew;
           stack.push_back(RK (rk._r + 1, rk._k) );
           stack.push_back(RK (rk._r - 1, rk._k) );
           stack.push_back(RK (rk._r, rk._k + 1) );
           stack.push_back(RK (rk._r, rk._k - 1) );
       }
   }
}
```

Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: ***which don't work at the moment*** and ***which don't work either*** What happened? It's difficult for us to debug didn't work.

Comment: you should point for code what expecrted behavior is and what actual behavior is. "it does not work" does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at my [example](https://ideone.com/YnjQn9).

For the version using the queue replace:

- `#include <stack>` with `#include <queue>`
- `std::stack` with `std:queue`
- `std::stack::top()` with `std::queue::front()`
- `std::stack::pop()` with `std::queue::pop_front()`
- `std::stack::push()` with `std::queue::push_back()`

Edit:
I decided to paste here at least filling function in case it would disappear in the internet.

```
using Point = std::pair<int, int>;

void fillUsingStack(bool m[W][H], int startX, int startY)
{
    std::stack<Point> S;
    S.push({startX, startY});

    while (!S.empty())
    {
        // get top element
        Point p = S.top();
        S.pop();

        // check boundaries
        if (p.first < 0 || p.first >= W || p.second < 0 || p.second >= H)
            continue;

        // skip when already colored
        if (m[p.first][p.second])
            continue;

        // color current tile
        m[p.first][p.second] = 1;

        // put all the neighbours on the stack
        S.push({p.first + 1, p.second});
        S.push({p.first - 1, p.second});
        S.push({p.first, p.second + 1});
        S.push({p.first, p.second - 1});
    }
}
```